# VS Code: Excluding files with same name but different Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I got a question regarding the file exclusion feature in VS Code.
Currently I am working with LaTex in VSC and I would like Code to ignore most of the master.* files being shown in the File Explorer, except of course the master.tex and master.pdf.

I tried adding some patterns to the settings.json:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "master.tex": false,
    "master.*": true,   
    "*.lol": true
},
```

As well as:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "master.*": true,
    "master.tex": false,   
    "*.lol": true
},
```

But these don't work, as they exclude all master.* files. I could of course add all the extension by hand, but I would really like there to be a more elegant solution.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Alex the question asked is not a duplicate in my opinion. The pattern of exclusion is different and the answer given there cannot apply to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no [Simple way](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/869) to do this but this syntax does what you want :

```
"files.exclude": {
    "master.[^tp]*": true, 
    "master.[^tp][^ed]*": true, 
    "master.[^tp][^ed][^xf]*": true, 
    "*.lol": true
},
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it solved the Problem! :)